# How do I make errors send to a specific channel?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Heyo,
I tried to do a "command" that sends error messages to my private discord channel, so I can see who and when it got ran. This is my code!

```
client.on('error', async guild => {
  let errorchannel = await client.channels.fetch('ID');
  if(!guild.available) return
  if(!guild.owner && guild.ownerID) await guild.members.fetch(guild.ownerID);
if(!deleteChannel) return;

  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setTitle(`Error!`)
.setDescription(`${guild.name}`)
.setColor("BLACK")
.setThumbnail(guild.iconURL())
.addField(`Owner`, `${guild.owner.user.tag}`)
.addField(`Error`, error)
.addField(`Member Count`, `${guild.memberCount}`)
.setFooter(`${guild.id}`)
errorchannel.send(embed);
});
```

Code from comments:

```
client.on('error', async (err) => {
  let errormsg = await client.channels.fetch('ID')

  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`Error!`)
    .setDescription(`${err.guild.name}`)
    .setColor("BLACK")
    .setThumbnail(err.guild.iconURL())
    .addField(`Owner`, `${err.guild.owner.user.tag}`)
    .addField(`Error`, err.message)
    .addField(`Member Count`, `${err.guild.memberCount}`)
    .setFooter(`${err.guild.id}`)
errormsg.send(embed);
});
```

Comment: Is your code throwing an error?

Comment: nope, just doesn't send anything

Comment: Does it even trigger your event when an error occurred ?

Comment: ¯\_____(ツ)_____/¯

Comment: Does `client.on("error")` even exist ?

Comment: Yea I don't think so

Comment: @Akio The first line of his code is `client.on('error', async guild => {`

Comment: Could you set a `breakpoint` at your second line `let errorchannel = await client.channels.fetch('ID');` and check if your bot reaches that line. If so, also check if `errorchannel` is `undefined`

Comment: The breakpoint is already there, and errorchannel isn't undefined

Comment: Then check if `guild.available` is `true` or `false`. If it is `false` you `return` without any message, etc. which could be the reason why nothing happens and you don't get any messages

Comment: `if(!guild.available) return`?

Comment: Yeah, in this line you are checking if the `available` property of `guild` is true or false. So set a breakpoint right there and check if `available` is true or false. Or change `if(!guild.available) return` to `if(!guild.available) return console.log('Guild is not available')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231364/discussion-between-toasty-and-axmyo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be slightly confused, `client.on("error")` **does** exist, however your function is wrong.

```js
client.on('error', async (err) => {
  let errorchannel = await client.channels.fetch('ID');
  //if(!guild.available) return
  //if(!guild.owner && guild.ownerID) await guild.members.fetch(guild.ownerID);
  //if(!deleteChannel) return; these lines need to be re-written, they do not work

  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`Error!`)
    .setDescription(`${err.guild.name}`)
    .setColor("BLACK")
    .setThumbnail(err.guild.iconURL())
    .addField(`Owner`, `${err.guild.owner.user.tag}`)
    .addField(`Error`, err.message)
    .addField(`Member Count`, `${err.guild.memberCount}`)
    .setFooter(`${err.guild.id}`)
  errorchannel.send(embed);
});
```

this should work, you had mixed up the syntax for `guild` and `error`

the reason nothing was sending is due to your error trapping with the `return` statements - since `guild.available` never exists as a function, it returned every time you ran the command.

Comment: But he checked the **property** `available` of `guild` and did not call it as `function`. It's just weird that it was always `false`

Comment: Still doesn't send anything

Comment: Yeah, because `guild.available` is 'false' and you return with no `message`. Remove this line and it should execute the rest of the code

Comment: the above code will run perfectly, i've tested it with my bot

Comment: Hmmm, when I get a error (ex: missing perms), it does not send anything anywhere.. 


Code edited in my question

Comment: if its missing permissions its nothing to do with my code, sort your permissions hierarchy in discord - the code is perfect